# Why does assigning text to a pointer store the memory location to the text?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I read somewhere that

```
char array[] = "abc";
```

sets the first four elements in the stack-stored array to `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and `'\0'`, and that:

```
char *pointer = "abc";
```

sets pointer to the address of the `"abc"` string. I understand why the first line of code behaves as it does, but why does the second--I would have expected there to be a chunk in the stack called "pointer", storing the hex/ASCII equivalent of `"abc"` (as a number corresponding to some arbitrary memory location). In other words, I would have expected `"abc"` to be stored as a memory address, since you're assigning it to a pointer, which stores memory addresses. Why does the computer instead choose to, counter-intuitively, store the *address* of `"abc"`, instead of storing `"abc"` (or a hex/numerical equivalent) itself, as a pointer?

Comment: The equivalent for integers is: `int *ptr = (int [4]){1, 2, 3, 4};` Arrays are often automatically converted to a pointer to their first element. This usual conversion is happening in the pointer assignment.

Comment: U aware that an adress and a pointer are the same things ?

Comment: In fact, the computer won't allocate memory in the heap if you don't ask it (with malloc for instance), so he puts everything on the stack ;) if it is true for int, it is true for arrays as well :)

Comment: [Initializing the array is a special case](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14)

Comment: @Angevil That is false, they aren't the same thing; and there are more places than just the stack and the heap -- which is actually where the string will be placed.

Comment: @Angevil: arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays. I suggest you read section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: As someone new to overflow, I'm curious why the question was downvoted?

Comment: @TanishqKumar Don't worry too much about the downvote.  Someone probably thought the question was too basic, or that you shouldn't have had the misconception you had, or something.  Anyway, I hope you have a better understanding now.  (Arrays and pointers in C are notoriously difficult to understand at first.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration `char array[] = "abc"` gives you a data structure that looks like this:

```
       +---+---+---+---+
array: | a | b | c |\0 |
       +---+---+---+---+
```

The declaration `char *pointer = "def"` gives you a data structure that looks like this:

```
         +-------+
pointer: |   *   |
         +---|---+
             |
             v
           +---+---+---+---+
           | d | e | f |\0 |
           +---+---+---+---+
```

Here, "def" essentially gets stored in an unnamed array that the compiler allocates somewhere, and `pointer` is initialized to point to it.

This applies more or less the same regardless of whether `array` and `pointer` are local or global (stack- or statically-allocated) variables.

It gets more interesting (or maybe more confusing) if we start actually printing these addresses:

```
printf("&pointer = %p, pointer = %p\n", &pointer, pointer);
printf("&array = %p, array = %p\n", &array, array);
```

When I ran this on my machine, I got:

```
&pointer = 0x102e99020, pointer = 0x102e98fa2
&array = 0x102e99018, array = 0x102e99018
```

So the address of the variable `array` is `0x102e99018`, and the address of the variable `pointer` is `0x102e99020`, and the unnamed array containing the string `"def"` is at address `0x102e98fa2`.

`pointer` is an ordinary pointer variable, so the pointer value it *contains* is different from the address of itself.  Since `array` is an array, however, you get its address whenever you mention it in an expression, so the pointer values of `array` and `&array` seem to be the same.